# Classification of ribbon graphs (reference request)

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology

Is there an explicit  classification of (isomorphism classes of) ribbon graphs (fat graphs) of low genus (say 0,1,2, maybe 3) with 'few' vertices (say less than 10)?

Thanks!